# Is this possible to run iphone app into ipad physical device from xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode8

I want to run iphone 7 size into ipad physical device. Is this possible to run iphone app into ipad physical device from xcode?

Comment: Yes. That is perfectly possible.

Comment: how is possible? explain me the steps

Answer (score 0):

In your XCode project settings, under Deployment Info > Devices, you have the choice between setting your app to iPhone, iPad, or Universal. Setting it to iPhone will make it so that your app will run in iPhone size, even on iPad devices.